# One-click WP site generation wih wp-cli on Windows

Tags: wp-cli, windows

If I run these commands sequentially in windows CMD, I get a site up and running quite quickly.

```
wp core download
wp core config --dbname=my_wp_database --dbuser=root --dbpass=my-db-password
wp core install --url=http://localhost/my-site-url --title="My WP Site" --admin_user=admin --admin_password=admin --admin_email=myemail@post.com
```

I'd love to make this even easier with a one-click script.

My attempt is below. It "nearly" works, but there are display issues on the resulting site.

Can anyone please give me a tweaked version that works properly and allows for spaces in the site name?

create-wp-site.cmd:

```
@echo off
set sitename="My Lovely Site"
set dbname="my_db_name"
mkdir %sitename%
cd %sitename%
start /wait wp core download
call wp core config --dbname=%dbname% --dbuser=root --dbpass=my_db_password
call wp core install --url=http://localhost/%sitename% --title=%name% --admin_user=admin --admin_password='admin' --admin_email=myemail@post.com
```

PS I'm aware this question is as much about Windows batch scripting as WP development, but I imagine a script like this would be of use to many WP developers so I'm posting here.

Comment: you dhould try to put quotes around whatever might contain spaces. If it needs escaping for whatever reason, probably best to ask on SO, I would assume not many doing much windows scripting around here.

Answer (score 1):

This is the script I use on Windows under XAMPP. It includes a MySQL command to create the database, and a tweak to improve security by nuking user 1 (and all its content) straight after install, resulting in a clean empty database.

```
@echo off
set dbName="wp_yourdbname"
set dbPass="your_random_db_password"
set siteUrl="sitename.localdev.yourdomain.com"
set siteName="Kluwell"
set siteDesc=""
set adminUser="Second User Name"
set adminPass="admin_password"
set adminEmail="admin-email@yourdomain.com"
:: these get nuked straight after install
set adminUserDummy="admin"
set adminUserDummyEmail="admin@example.com"

SET /P AREYOUSURE=This will nuke the current site %siteUrl% and the DB %dbName%. Are you sure (Y/[N])?
IF /I "%AREYOUSURE%" NEQ "Y" GOTO END

REM SQL setup
mysql -u root -p -e "DROP USER IF EXISTS %dbName%@localhost;DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS %dbName%;CREATE USER %dbName%@localhost IDENTIFIED BY '%dbPass%';CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS %dbName%; GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON %dbName% . * TO %dbName%@localhost;exit;"

REM setup core
call wp core download
call wp core config --dbname=%dbName% --dbuser=%dbName% --dbpass=%dbPass%
call wp core install --url=%siteUrl% --title=%siteName% --admin_user=%adminUserDummy% --admin_password=%adminPass% --admin_email=%adminUserDummyEmail%

REM remove first user
call wp user create %adminUser% %adminEmail% --role=administrator --user_pass=%adminPass%
call wp user delete 1 --yes
```

Works a treat, especially if you set up a wildcard DNS entry to point `*.localdev.yourdomain.com` to `127.0.0.1` and configure `mod_vhost_alias` under Apache so that you can serve all the localdev sites out of a single directory, one subdir per host, so creating a subdirectory of `dave` equates to a url of `dave.localhost.yourdomain.com`